# Sum a column when another column is true in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-aggregation

I have a table with a a name, a score and a flag:

```
Name    Score    Flag
----------------------
Fred    10       true
Fred    10       false
Bob     10       false
```

I'm trying to group by the name, and in two columns get the sum of the score, and the sum of the score only when the flag is true, eg:

```
Name    Score    FlagTrueScore
------------------------------
Fred    20       10
Bob     10       0
```

I found a way to do this by creating two temporary tables, one with the score, and one with the flagtruescore, then joining them. But I'm wondering if there is an easier, more elegant, or more recommended way, maybe with a window function or something like that?

Comment: Flag column data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `case` sum. Try, like:

```
Select Name, Sum(Score), SUM(CASE When Flag Then Score Else 0 End ) as FlagTrueScore    
from myTable group by Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select name, sum(score) score,
max(case when flag=true then score end) FlagTrueScore
from tablename
group by name
```